# Public water taps in Palmer AK

Tags: tap-water, alaska

I would like to find public water taps in Palmer, Alaska, USA.

Comment: What a cool question !

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you looking for water fountains where you can refill your bottle/thermos, or a fresh water hose to refill the potable tank on a camper or RV?

Comment: to refill larger water containers used when camping out

Answer (score 8):

While this one's about an hour away, if you're in a pinch, [here is, apparently, some of the most delicious drinking water available in Alaska](http://www.alaska.org/detail/fresh-water-spring).  It's just south of Anchorage.

> Drive just a few miles south of Anchorage, and you can taste the best
>   water that Alaska has to offer. No fees, no gimmicks: just a 5-foot
>   pipe protruding from a granite cliff face that gushes crystal clear
>   water capable of causing instant brain freezes. Locals stop regularly
>   to fill up bottles for hiking and skiing trips because the water
>   tastes fantastic and they love the fact that there’s no chlorine,
>   fluoride, or throwaway plastic bottles involved. Despite cars rushing
>   by on the highway, you get a serene sense of connectedness with bygone
>   generations, whom you can imagine getting pristine water from similar
>   sources all over the state.
>
> A Water Pipe with a Pedigree
>
> This pipe was installed decades ago by
>   the DOT, to relieve pressure from an underground spring and allow it
>   to pass harmlessly under the highway. What started as a simple
>   engineering exercise has become a boon for health-conscious and
>   environmentally minded travelers and locals who flock here to fill up
>   their bottles. In one 15 minute period its easy to observe four or
>   five different cars pull up to get water, some carrying five-gallon
>   jugs. The flow varies with the seasons and rainfall, but generally you
>   can fill up a gallon jug in a matter of seconds.
>
> Look for the Pullout
>
> Granted, there’s nothing to mark the spot other
>   than a large pullout on the inlet side of the highway, so keep your
>   eyes peeled and definitely use the parking area. Traffic moves faster
>   on this section of highway than in most other areas of the state, so
>   it’s especially important to park off the road. Crossing the highway
>   may require a short wait, but it’s worth the trouble. Bring several
>   water bottles to stock up, and don’t be surprised if a couple locals
>   are there loading up, too. If you have time, the beachside rocks are a
>   great place for a picnic while watching the regular summer bore tide
>   or scoping for belugas.

Comment: Unfortunately the link now includes this update: “As of March 27, 2019, this area is now closed. After the November 30, 2018 earthquake, it is a high rock-fall risk area. We'll keep an eye out for a new great spot to grab fresh Alaska water!”